# Verilog generate statement issue

Tags: verilog

I was trying to use the `generate` function in Verilog.  The code compiled successfully, but it couldn't simulate.  I get the following errors:

```
Illegal output or inout port connection for "port 'sum'".
Illegal output or inout port connection for "port 'carry'".
```

Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
module test(input wire [2:0] a, 
        input wire [2:0] b,
        output reg [2:0] s,
        output reg [2:0] c);

genvar i;
generate 
for(i=0;i<3;i=i+1)
    adder_half inst(.sum(s[i]),.carry(c[i]),.a(a[i]),.b(b[i]));
endgenerate 

endmodule

module adder_half(
  output sum,carry,
  input a,b
    );
 xor(sum,a,b);
 and(carry,a,b);

endmodule
```

Comment: I didn't made one, I directly used the tool's( ModelSim) simulate option.

Comment: I changed my adder output type to reg, still I'm getting the same error. module adder_half(
    output reg sum,carry,
  input a,b
    );
always@(*) 
begin
 sum=a^b;
 carry=a&b;
end 
endmodule

Comment: Sorry my fault, and thanks it started working, but am i not supposed to use reg type inside blocks (here its generate block)

Comment: The type is only relevant for current module. an output of `reg` is connected to `wire` at the next level of hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `reg` type is only used for procedural assignments, but instance connections are treated more like continuous assignments.

Remove the `reg` keyword from your outputs.  Change:

```
    output reg [2:0] s,
    output reg [2:0] c);
```

to:

```
    output [2:0] s,
    output [2:0] c);
```